# How can I make a custom counter in the MapReduce engine?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to make a my counter to check the operation time of Maptask.run and ReduceTask.run using global counter or even LOG.info().

In a pseudo-distributed mode, using builded mapreduce-core-snapshot.jar which I modified in the MapTask.java and ReduceTask.java to make my goal, it works perfectly as I expected.

However, in a real cluster, the source code I injected isn't work and just system-default counter variables are showing.

I think there are different logging logic or security issue between pseudo-distributed and cluster mode, but I am not sure about that.

Is there anyone who can let me know about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Q:How can I make a custom counter
```

Ans :

```
public static enum MyGroupName {
   MyGroupName;
   MYCOUNTTWO;
};

MyMap extends Mapper<..>{
map(...){
// ... your code 
// get counter 
counter one=context.getCounter(MyGroupName, MyGroupName);
// set counter 
context.incrCounter(MyGroupName.MyGroupName,TIMEOFTASK);
}

}
```

---

Comment: Thanks but not in my custom mapreduce application, but in the internal of mapreduce engine.